# How can we sort views in DOORS

Tags: ibm-doors

when i create a new view in DOORS for a given module it generally goes to the end of all other views which are already there for the module. is it possible to move the newly created view to the top of the list just below the standard view, if so how ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help you get the best result on Stack Overflow, see how to ask good [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Make sure your question covers these 3 elements: 1. Problem Statement 2. Your Code (it should be [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 3. Error Message (preferably full Traceback to help others review and provide feedback). Sometimes the same question may have already been asked. Make sure your question is not a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, new views do not go to the end of all other views. They are always sorted alphabetically (first view will always be "Standard View", then follow the views beginning with 0-9 then with A-Z, then with a-z). So, if you want to sort your views, you will need a naming convention according to your needs.

Comment: I thought it would be the same, Thanks for confirming.